How can I show an unauthorized view when HttpClient gets 403 from calling API in .NET Blazor Web Assembly?
Basically here is my scenario that I'm going to achieve:

I have two users: A and B, A has the permission to access my Restful API developed with ASP.NET Core Web API, B doesn't have the permission to access that API resource (API will return 403)
In my Blazor Web Assembly app, there is a page which will read data from this Restful API, so, I would like when A user logs in, s/he can access this page correctly, but when B logs in, since B doesn't have the access to the API, therefore, when the page is loading and reading data from API, the page will get 403 error and should instead show something like "You don't have permission to access the page"

So, in the OnInitializedAsync method of the Blazor page, it uses injected IHttpClientFactory to create an HttpClient, and makes a call to the API:
using var httpClient = HttpClientFactory.CreateClient("stickersHttpClient");
var httpResponseMessage = await httpClient.GetAsync($"api/stickers?page={pageNumber}&size={pageSize}");
httpResponseMessage.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
var responseJson = await httpResponseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
PageContent = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<StickersPage>(responseJson);

If it is user B who opens this page, the httpClient.GetAsync will definitely return 403 error, but instead of showing a "You don't have permission to view this page" error on the page, the page actually reported an error in the console:

I have already applied @attribute [Authorize] on the page, and in the App.razor it has the following authorized view settings:
<CascadingAuthenticationState>
    <Router AppAssembly="@typeof(App).Assembly">
        <Found Context="routeData">
            <AuthorizeRouteView RouteData="@routeData" DefaultLayout="@typeof(MainLayout)">
                <NotAuthorized>
                    @if (context.User.Identity?.IsAuthenticated != true)
                    {
                        <RedirectToLogin />
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        <p role="alert">You don't have permission to view this page.</p>
                    }
                </NotAuthorized>
            </AuthorizeRouteView>
            <FocusOnNavigate RouteData="@routeData" Selector="h1" />
        </Found>
        <NotFound>
            <PageTitle>Not found</PageTitle>
            <LayoutView Layout="@typeof(MainLayout)">
                <p role="alert">Sorry, there's nothing at this address.</p>
            </LayoutView>
        </NotFound>
    </Router>
</CascadingAuthenticationState>

I think there should be some gap between the API and the page, there should be the way allowing my razor page to "know" about the 403 returned by the API so that it could apply the routed authentication view. But I don't know how can I do that.
(By the way, the authorization of the user is done against Keycloak with the policy based on user roles)

The EnsureSuccessStatusCode method throws an exception if the HTTP response was unsuccessful. You have to check for 403 manually

@jeb Thanks! so you mean I should try...catch this 403 manually and do whatever like redirecting to a new page or similar, right?

Yes, you can take the response check the status code and then do whatever you want based on the status code.

If you want to go to the <NotAuthorized> depending on the httpclient call response. You have to trigger an authenticationState permission check failure . Such as create a never authorized page like follwing.
NeverAuth.razor
@page "/neverAuth"
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization
@attribute [Authorize(Roles ="nonExistRole")]

Then navigate to this page manually
@inject NavigationManager _navigationManager
...
        var httpResponseMessage = await httpClient.GetAsync($"api/stickers?page={pageNumber}&size={pageSize}");
        if (httpResponseMessage.StatusCode == 403)
        {
            _navigationManager.NavigateTo("/neverAuth");
        }
        var responseJson = await httpResponseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();


Thank you for your answer! I will firstly go with this approach.
